# Desrialize XML with xsi:type

Tags: c#, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Payload DataType="Tax" DataFormat="Standard" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <TaxReturn>
        <ReturnHeader ClientID="ABC" TaxYear="2017" ReturnType="F" ReturnGroupName="Default" Country="US" OfficeName="Dev" BusinessUnitName="Returns" ConfigurationSet="Default" ReturnVersion="1" EINorSSN="" ControlNumber="202011170947577107"/>
        <TaxPayerDetails NameLine1="CCC" NameLine2=""/>
        <View xsi:type="Worksheet">
            <Identifier Hierarchy="Federal\General\Basic Data"/>
            <Controls>
                <Entity ID="1"/>
            </Controls>
            <WorkSheetSection Name="General">
                <FieldData Location="Entity Type" LocationType="Description" Value="Simple"/>
                <FieldData Location="Entity Name Line 1" LocationType="Description" Value="test"/>
            </WorkSheetSection>
            <WorkSheetSection Name="Other Information"/>
            <WorkSheetSection Name="Direct Deposit / Electronic Funds Withdrawal"/>
        </View>
    </TaxReturn>
</Payload>
```

Above is my xml.

And this is my c# object

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "TaxReturn")]
    public class TaxReturn
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ReturnHeader")]
        public ReturnHeader ReturnHeader { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TaxPayerDetails")]
        public TaxPayerDetails TaxPayerDetails { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "View", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public View View { get; set; }
    }

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "View")]
    public class View
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Identifier")]
        public Identifier Identifier { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Controls")]
        public Controls Controls { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "WorkSheetSection")]
        public WorkSheetSection[] WorkSheetSection { get; set; }   
    }
```

And I am getting null when I try to get View object -when deserializing it.

I think it is about namespace declaration, but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you've posted correct XML? The `View` node has default (empty) namespace in the example you've posted.

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

`<View xsi:type="Worksheet">` this means that the real type of the `View` is `Worksheet` type.

Create the base class `View`. Inherit the `Worksheet` class from it.

With the `XmlInclude` attribute specify valid types.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "TaxReturn")]
public class TaxReturn
{
    ...

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "View")]
    public View View { get; set; }
}

[XmlInclude(typeof(Worksheet))]
public class View { }

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "View")]
public class Worksheet : View
{
    ...
}
```